# Haskell haddock automatic documentation

Tags: haskell, documentation-generation, haddock

I have not been able to generate documentaion for haskell using haddock.

So far I have not found any useful examples. The documentation has a lot of options and also I am not sure about the comment syntax so that documentation is correctly generated.

I know that inside ghci I can call :bro for loaded files and it lists types and functions, I wish these functions could be documented with haddock even without comments. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: Er, `cabal haddock` and done? — This question asks some rather different things, I think you should narrow it down to one subject lest it be closed as too broad.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It is not just that. I tried and it only created one link to the main package I want a list of functions contained in the program like when I do :bro in ghci. Also I would like to know where to  dd this command in the setup file so that it is generated instead of me having to call cabal for each command individually. It is not that trivial. And I'd say there are very poor and few examples on comment syntax to generate documentation.

Comment: Ah, now I see what's the issue (this is actually about module exports). Please edit so the answers can actually match the question, not just the comment to the question...

Comment: I am new to haskell so I am not familiar with terminology. I understan there is a main module, but I dont need it in the documentation. I have very simple files which dont even contain classes, just some types and functions, I don't know if I can document those. Can you help me rephrase the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you build an *executable*, like

```
module Main (main) -- this line is implicit if your module isn't named otherwise
   where

-- | Some important function that does most of the work
foo :: Bar -> Baz
foo = ...

-- Other definitions
-- ...

-- | The program you want to run.
main :: IO ()
main = ...

-- ...
```

then Haddock assumes there's nothing public to actually document – after all, `main` is the only thing someone using that project actually gets to call, everything else is hidden!

To generate also documentation for `foo`, you need to *export* it, either directly from the `Main` module or from another module where it's originally defined. The usual way to go is to put everything really interesting in some “internal” modules, like

```
module Foo (foo, {- other stuff ... -}) where

-- | Some important function that does most of the work
foo :: Bar -> Baz
foo = ...

-- Other definitions
-- ... but not `main`
```

and for the executable only use an “end user scratch-resistant plastic wrapper” module

```
module Main (main) where

import Foo

main :: IO ()
main = ...
```

Then the documentation for `Foo` will contain the actually interesting Haskell API Haddocks. This will then look like

> ### Foo
>
> **`foo`** :: `Bar` -> `Baz`
> Some important function that does most of the work

Actually, you'll want to write the documentation something like

```
-- | Transmogrify a bare bar into a zapcutted one
foo :: Bar -- ^ The bare input to transmogrify
    -> Baz -- ^ The zapcutted wrimch
```

yielding documentation looking like

> ### Foo
>
> **`foo`** ::
>
> - `Bar` The bare input to transmogrify
> - -> `Baz` The zapcutted wrimch
>
> Transmogrify a bare bar into a zapcutted one

The Haddock for `Main` isn't really interesting, you might better put the information in some command-line help box.

In the `project.cabal` file, you then need to classify `Foo` as belonging to the “library” part of the project, whereas `Main` is the executable part.

Basically, Haddock is just for libraries, not for executables.